# angular js google map unable to use google event listener for marker

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am testing out angular js google map http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api

I can add multiple marker on the map, however i am unable to set the event listener to each marker. i just want it to write into console when user click any of the marker.

How can i make my codes work?

Below are my codes:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org/" ng-app="appMaps">

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=weather,geometry,visualization,places&sensor=false&language=en&v=3.17"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.26"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/master/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--css-->
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, #map_canvas {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #map_canvas {
            position: relative;
        }

        .angular-google-map-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script>angular.module('appMaps', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
      .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: 34.963916,
        longitude: 104.311893
      },
      zoom: 4,
      bounds: {},

    };

    $scope.options = {
      scrollwheel: false
    };
    var createRandomMarker = function(i, bounds, idKey) {
      var lat_min = bounds.southwest.latitude,
        lat_range = bounds.northeast.latitude - lat_min,
        lng_min = bounds.southwest.longitude,
        lng_range = bounds.northeast.longitude - lng_min;

      if (idKey == null) {
        idKey = "id";
      }

      var latitude = lat_min + (Math.random() * lat_range);
      var longitude = lng_min + (Math.random() * lng_range);
      var ret = {
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        title: 'm' + i
      };
      ret[idKey] = i;
      return ret;
    };
    $scope.randomMarkers = [];
    // Get the bounds from the map once it's loaded
    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return $scope.map.bounds;
    }, function(nv, ov) {
      // Only need to regenerate once
      if (!ov.southwest && nv.southwest) {
        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {   
             var ret = {
            latitude:  34.963916,
            longitude: 104.311893,
            title: 'm3',
            id: 1
            };

            var ret2 = {
            latitude:  37.096002,
            longitude: 126.987675,
            title: 'm2',
            id:2
            };
           markers.push(ret);
           markers.push(ret2);

        }
        $scope.randomMarkers = markers;
      }
    }, true);

    $scope.marker = {
        events:{click: console.log('click')},
    }

     });


  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map_canvas" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" bounds="map.bounds" events = "'map.events'">
        <ui-gmap-markers models="randomMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" click="'test'" events = "'events'"></ui-gmap-markers>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>

</div>
<!--example-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will look further into this later today. One way I can think of at the moment is to set the `click` argument in `<ui-gmap-markers>` to a valid JS function that calls `console.log()`.

In my case, I made `click="onClick"` and then defined the following function:

```
$scope.onClick = function onClick() {
console.log("click");}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Click Event on google map** 

i am not know about map api in angular but i had some suggestions 
you can use map api with canvas you can give ng-click event on canvas element 
code is  here

 site:
jsfiddle.net/xSPAA/536/